# Change color of tab bar

Tags: ios, tabs, controller, appearance

I created an app in iOS 5 using Storyboard to lay out my screens.  I have a tab bar controller and the bottom tab bar with 4 icons.  I want to change the color from black to a graduated green.  I can make a .png file, but can't figure out how to replace the black fill with my green fill.

I've seen some posts on code to do this but seems iOS 5 is different than if the device is running iOS4 and I can't figure out where to put the code.

Thx

Answer (score 4):

Here is what worked for me:

In AppDelegate.m I put the following code after // Override point for customization after application launch.

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

You can either set the color on the storyboard by selecting the root: Tab Bar View Controller, select the tab bar, and adjust the Background (or tint) color in the attributes inspector, or you can adjust the code with the barTintColor:

```html
// Adjust the Color of the Tab Bar itself
self.tabBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];

// Adjust the Color of the selected Icon in the Tab Bar
self.tabBar.tintColor = [Single single].singleThemeColorTint;
```

If you need to adjust the ALPHA too, I would use:

```html
UIColor *charcoal = [UIColor colorWithRed:66/255.0
                                            green:79/255.0
                                             blue:91/255.0
                                            alpha:1];
   // For Tab Bar
    self.tabBar.barTintColor = charcoal;

 // For selected Item Highlight
    self.tabBar.tintColor = charcoal;
```

I created a View Controller File for the Tab Bar Story Board, and ran this code in ViewDidLoad{ }

Answer (score 0):

Here is the wonderful blog post of Ray WenderLich.

User Interface Customization in iOS5

> http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5

Comment: Thanks, I go over that tutorial and see if I can figure out the color change.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created your application using storyboard API, then you cannot support iOS4, they rely on new runtime classes which are not available there.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that.  In your opinion is there much of a negative releasing an app that will not run on iOS 4?

Comment: No, as  most of the devices have got iOS5 updates and iOS6 release is round the corner... Apple would try and deprecate many framework support in pre-iOS5 SDKs